# Javascript. Cyclical when clicking the link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a JS script for clicking on links that contain ".xyz". This is worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var links = document.querySelector('a[href*=".xyz"]').href;
    window.location.href = links;
}
</script>
```

This try to click on link ad unit. But click here seems to be satisfied, but there is a cycle in which constantly comes back to the homepage. Help me please. thanks in advance

For example: Go to synthcafe.ru and you will see a cyclical

Comment: I'm now sure when can your code work. What you are doing is: *On load, fetch a.xyz's href and redirect on it*. Now if `a.xyz` has `#` as url, it will go on and on as everytime you set href, it will refresh page and window.load will call again

Comment: It's clear. But how to fix it? It is necessary that there was a click on the ad unit when the page loads. But he does not do it :(

Comment: Check for href if it is either `#` or is same as current location, dont set

Comment: you should change window.onload with a click eventlistener

Comment: Thank you. Show me please on example or my code

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens:

1) Your page loads.

2) window.onload is called

3) window.location.href is set to a different(?) value, so it loads the new url

4) Your page loads. => See 1), all starting again

You should remove the window.href statement from window.onload

Comment: Thank you. how to fix it? It is necessary that there was a click on the ad unit when the page loads. But he does not do it :(